Fill in blanks in returned array with last filled-in value
I have a LET function that returns an incomplete array, like:
Header 1    Header 2
Value 1      3
             4
Value 2      5
             6

What I want is
Header 1    Header 2
Value 1      3
Value 1      4
Value 2      5
Value 2      6

I thought a byRow Lambda combo might work, but I don't know how to reference Value X (from the row above)  when the current row is blank.
This is the old LET function:
=LET(dataset,HSTACK(Sheet1!M1:M1000,Sheet1!P3:AH1003),f,FILTER(dataset,ISNUMBER(INDEX(dataset,,18))),HSTACK(INDEX(f,,1),INDEX(f,,2),INDEX(f,,4),INDEX(f,,18)))

And this is what I modified it to using SCAN to fill in the blanks:
=LET(f,LET(dataset,HSTACK(Sheet1!M1:M1000,Sheet1!P3:AH1003),f,FILTER(dataset,ISNUMBER(INDEX(dataset,,18))),HSTACK(INDEX(f,,1),INDEX(f,,2),INDEX(f,,4),INDEX(f,,18))),r,SCAN(INDEX(f,1,1),INDEX(f,,1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b<>"",b,a))),HSTACK(r,DROP(f,,1)))

Thanks for the hint about SCAN. Exactly what I needed.

This worked for me = the nested LET is my original formula:
=LET(f,LET(dataset,HSTACK(Sheet1!M1:M1000,Sheet1!P3:AH1003),
     f,FILTER(dataset,ISNUMBER(INDEX(dataset,,18))),
  HSTACK(INDEX(f,,1),INDEX(f,,2),INDEX(f,,4),INDEX(f,,18))),
  r,SCAN(INDEX(f,1,1),INDEX(f,,1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b<>"",b,a))),HSTACK(r,DROP(f,,1)))

